# PyQt4 Missing in import statement

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I tried to download PyQt4 however it no lomger appears to be available, so I downloaded the nearest thing to it that I could find PyQt-win-gpl-4.8.4. The problem is when I try to follow the examples in "Rapid GUI programming with Python and QT" i cannot use some of the imports e.g. from PyQt4.QtCore import * gives me the following Error (copied from IDLE):

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
`import sys
`import time
`from PyQt4.QtCore import *

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>>**
```

Comment: PyQt4 is still available

Answer (score 3):

You downloaded a source package, so you'd have to compile everything. Try the binary package at the bottom of [Riverbank's page](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download). As you have python 2.7 on a 32bit system, you want to download `PyQt-Py2.7-x86-gpl-4.8.4-1.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you could just intall pyqt4 with either:

```
pip install pyqt4
```

or

```
easy_insatll pyqt4
```

or

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download

-> under Binary Packages choose the one that correspondends to your python version and system

for you this schould be the right one: [pyqt4 py2.7 32bit](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py2.7-x86-gpl-4.8.4-1.exe)

Comment: I tried your link pyqt4 py2 7 32bit and it downloaded the same version of PyQt that I downloaded. Not PyQt4
I am running windows 7 what is pip
what is easy_install

Comment: alright is this the first time you using python? easy_install and pip are both ways you can install additional libraries or packages to python easy_install comes with python..., to install python and pyqt you just executed the .exe file?